# How can I assign types for an array of objects that extend the same class?

Tags: typescript

This might be a stupid question as I'm new to typescript, however, I have the following scenario. I have an array that contains objects that all extend the same class. For example:

```
class Body{
 // implementation
}

class Rectangle extends Body{
 // implementation
}

class Circle extends Body{
 // implementation
}

const box: Rectangle = new Rectangle()
const circle: Circle = new Circle()

const world: Array<Body> = [box, circle]
```

The problem I have is that when I am accessing methods on the elements in the array, I'm getting an error that they don't exist on the Body class (which they don't). I'm wondering if there is a correct way to do this or if I am doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to create abstract methods in the `Body` class that can be implemented by subclasses. This way you would have different behaviour but same methods - polymorphism. F.e.:

```
abstract class Body {
  abstract area(): number;
}
```

and then subclasses can have the implementation.

If it does not make sense to have same method names in different classes, then you must check the object's class with `instanceof` as [Alex Wayne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72471878/7097045) said.

Answer (score 1):

`Array<Body>` says that the array elements are only guaranteed to implement the `Body` interface.

If you want to have an array of `Body` instances that might be subclasses, then you have to do a runtime check first to make sure the object is what you expect it to be.

```
const world: Array<Body> = [box, circle]

if (world[0] instanceof Rectangle) {
    world[0].someRectangleOnlyMethod()
}
```

This is required because this would crash since that method wouldn't exist on `Circle` instances:

```
world[1].someRectangleOnlyMethod() // crash
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?preserveConstEnums=true&target=99&preserveValueImports=false&isolatedModules=false&allowSyntheticDefaultImports=false&inlineSources=false&preserveWatchOutput=false&ts=4.6.4#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2ATAngbwFDS9MAKAlNKtAE4CmALgK4kB20A5GA9AL7rvqiQwBKZwCmFoBzEGWhkAHhTK1EMBCgzZoAIwJFSlGvQZqW7TtyjQAwgEsSoCdNnzFSNJmzBNxctTqNghjui54WggKdXgpAC5ofkFhMQkAXmhaMgB3aIEhUXECQODQ4CsbKMtrcWgklPTSm1y8kOhU+BIQRCiAQRISMGQAHiVkAD4K6ABtNXCAGmhCsrIAXQCLADNoXCaWxFGABnnoC3zhYDJ4VZis+MIVbA3WnfmAOg1CAHoXxuaAawh-IA)

Answer (score 0):

Though in most cases you do want either Alex Wayne's or Uroš Anđelić's approaches, there is also

```
const world = [box, circle] as const;
```

in which case the type of `world` will be inferred as `[Box, Circle]` and you can call `Box`'s methods on `world[0]`.